# How to sort by the attributes of classes in Python?

Tags: python

I have two classes set up (with some other attributes that are irrelevant).

```
class Alcohol():
    def __init__(FunctionalGroup):
        FunctionalGroup.Naming = ["hydroxy", "ol"]

class Halogenoalkane():
    def __init__(FunctionalGroup):
        FunctionalGroup.Naming = ["chloro", "bromo", "iodo"]
```

I want to be able to sort a given string such as `ethanol` or `2-chloromethane` into one of these and create an instance based on which class the name fits into. For example:

```
>>> Name: Ethanol
This is an alcohol.
```

I am looking for a way to iterate over the `FunctionalGroup.Naming` list in each class and check if any of them are contained in the string.

What is the best approach to doing this or alternative data structures?

(Sorry if you don't like chemistry I'm just trying to make revising it more interesting)

Comment: @timgeb I am trying to identify the functional group of an IUPAC compound name.

Comment: So ethanol would  match "ol" in the Alcohol class and 2-chloromethane would match "chloro" in the Halogenoalkane class?  What do you want to return, the class or the string that matches?

Comment: @JonathanRys the class that matches, so that I can create an instance.

Comment: What about compounds like chloro-ethanol?

Comment: @Feodoran for the purpose of A-level chemistry that won't happen, but yes that is a big flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the cleanest way of doing it, and I removed the instance variables and made a constant list in each class instead. This way it is easier to reference, and the list seems like a constant anyhow:

```
class Alcohol():
    Naming = ["hydroxy", "ol"]

    def __init__(self):
        print ' ---> Alcohol'

class Halogenoalkane():
    Naming = ["chloro", "bromo", "iodo"]

    def __init__(self):
        print ' ----> Halogen'

str = 'hydroxy'
classes = [Alcohol, Halogenoalkane]

chosen_class = object
for cl in classes:
    if str in cl.Naming:
        chosen_class = cl

print '{} is an:'.format(str)

obj = chosen_class()  # instantiate the class
```

output:

```
hydroxy is an:
 ---> Alcohol
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a basic version of what I was trying to understand. :)